# How can I divide a range into n equal bins?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have  a  range *[min-max]*. *min* and *max* are of type `double`. I want to divide this interval into n equal intervals.(n is an integer). How can I achieve this in Java?

For example :
say I have a range `[10-50]`. and `n=4` .
output should be a list of ranges like `[10-20] [20-30][30-40] [40-50]`

Comment: double interval = (double)(max-min)/n;

Comment: Do you just want to divide them equally or distribute randomly as well?

Answer (score 3):

So what you need here is a formula for the limits of the smaller ranges. First lets start off by computing the length of each small range:

```
// let range be [start, end]
// let the number of smaller ranges be n
double total_length = end - start;
double subrange_length = total_length/n;
```

After that do a simple cycle for the smaller ranges moving the left end of the current range with the value computed above on each step:

```
double current_start = start;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  System.out.printl("Smaller range: [" + current_start + ", " + (current_start + subrange_length) + "]");
  current_start += subrange_length;
}
```

Comment: What if the numbers can be negative? e.g. from -32768 to +32767

Comment: @KamilDziedzic there is no reason for this not to work with negative numbers. However make sure that the difference between the end and the start does not overflow the type you are using - for instance for short and the interval you provided this could overflow

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use what @Achintya used, `double dist = (double)(max-min)/n;` Then starting from the min, add dist to it and that is the max of your first interval.

So it'd be something like:
`[min, min + dist], [min + dist, min + 2*dist]...` until `min + n*dist >= max.`

```
int counter = 0;
while(true) {
    CreateInterval(min + counter*dist, min + (counter+1)*dist);
    if (min+(counter+1)*dist >= max) {
         //if we have reached the max, we are done
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you keep adding dist to the minimum, you're going to get rounding errors over a large number of ranges.  It's better to multiply the range count by the dist, then add that to the minimum to get the current range minimum.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'm sorry, I don't quite see the difference between the two ways you said. I realize since dist is a rounded double, I'll get rounding errors for large number of ranges, but could you explain the second way you mentioned a bit more?

Comment: I think he just means multiple `dist` by `counter` since that's one operation instead of doing multiple `dist` adds which each have rounding errors. I can not attest to the truth of the claim... only that there will be fewer operations (it is not obvious to me that that means there will be less rounding error).

Comment: Never mind.  I see you're doing in the code what I described.  My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If have the Range given in the form of an array with two elements (min and max)

```
double[] range = new double[] {min, max};
int n = 4;
```

you could try it this way. What you get from `divideRange` is a two-dimensional array with subranges of the given range, with each of them having the wanted length.

```
public double[][] divideRange(double[] range, n) {
    double[][] ranges = new double[n][2];
    double length = (range[1] - range[0])/n;
    ranges[0][0] = range[0];
    ranges[0][1] = range[0]+length;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        ranges[i][0] = ranges[i-1][1];
        ranges[i][1] = ranges[i-1][1]+length;
    }

    return ranges;
}
```